# Terminology "above and beyond"

Tags: regression, terminology

What do researchers mean when they say predictor X accounted for a significant amount of variance **above and beyond** predictor A?

Comment: Where exactly did you see the phrase? My best guess is that they meant “higher”.

Comment: They likely are comparing a model in which both $X$ and $A$ are used as explanatory variables to one in which everything is the same but $X$ has not been included.  @Tim this is a more complicated meaning than merely "higher."

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> They likely are comparing a model in which both $$ and $$ are used
> as explanatory variables to one in which everything is the same but
> $$ has not been included. @Tim this is a more complicated meaning
> than merely "higher."

-whuber